# extract from pandas dataframe into new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

so lets say i have a pandas dataframe which has three columns, Account Number, Date, and Volume.

i want to be able to create a new dataframe with the same columns but filtered by a prompt i chose (in this case 2022-08-17) and all accounts.

in reality the sheet is much larger and has alot of accounts.

see example below:

[image]

thank you

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far. And please use correct upper case letters. Don't show data as images. Post them as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need:

```
(df[df['Prompt'].eq('2022-08-17')]
.groupby(['Account', 'Prompt'], as_index=False)
.sum()
)
```

Output:

*No output provided as the input format was an image*